# What is the the probability that it will rain on Mon or Tue or wed?

Tags: probability

If the probability of rain is 1/2 for any given day. What is the the probability that it will rain on Mon or Tue or wed?

Comment: Without further assumptions, that question cannot be answered. The obvious assumption, independence, is extremely unrealistic in this case, unless the days are meant to be from different weeks.

Comment: @celtschk in the question it says the probability of rain is 1/2 'for any given day', so independence exists - otherwise it isn't always going to be 1/2

Comment: @AndrewDeighton: No, that's not true. If it either rains every day, or rains at none of the days, but both possibilities have the same probability, then for every day the probability of rain is $1/2$, but there is clearly no independence.

Comment: @celtschk if I say 'it rained on Monday, what is the probability it rained on Tuesday'  - Tuesday is the day I gave you, and it is 1/2.  If I said '50% of days have rain', then I haven't given you enough info.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton: Of course after Monday, the probabilities will change. In particular, at that point, the probability that it rained on Monday will **not** be $1/2$, but $1$ (because it rained on Monday). But if I ask on Sunday "what is the probability that it rains on Tuesday", the probability is $1/2$, not $0$ and not $1$. And "50% of days have rain" is a **completely** different statement. Indeed, it's a statement which we from the beginning know is false, as there are exactly three days in the problem, and there's no way 50% of those days can have rain.

Comment: @ celtschk that's not what you said in the first place, you implied that the probability of rain on a future day might not be 1/2 - if there is not independence then the probability of rain on a future day is not always 1/2, if it is always 1/2, then there is independence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about all the possible combinations of ways the weather could play out over the 3 days! Essentially, we want it to rain at least once out of the 3 days. We denote each possible outcome as a string $A_1 A_2 A_3$ where $A_i$ is either $R$ (rainy) or $N$ (not rainy) on the $i$th day, where Monday is the 1st. Then the set of all possible outcomes is $$\{RRR, RRN, RNR, RNN, NRR, NRN, NNR, NNN\}.$$ Now count the number of possible outcomes that has at least one $R$, and then divide by the total number of possible outcomes.

---

EDIT: I'd like to add that we could obtain the same answer another, more intuitive way: find the probability that it doesn't rain on Monday AND it doesn't rain on Tuesday AND it doesn't rain on Wednesday, which is given by $1/2 \times 1/2 \times 1/2$. Since this is the only case where it doesn't rain at all, we subtract $1/8$ from 1 because we want the probability that it rains at least once, or in other words, the probability that it DOESN'T rain on all three days.

Comment: so it is 7/8...?

Comment: You are correct! :)

Comment: thnx for the update  :)